# Geometry: Using Pythagorean Theorem to find lengths of triangle

Tags: geometry

I am helping someone do their geometry homework, and wanted to make sure I am even doing it correctly. Below is the problem:
[image: Find the length of BF]

Here is how I solved it:
We know B is the center, so AB=BE. EF=$\frac{EC}{2}$
Then, use Pythagorean theorem so find BF.

## 10. EC=14 so EF=7. AB=16=BE. $16^2=7^2+b^2 \rightarrow BF=3\sqrt{23}$.

Is this correct? I did the same for the rest, but the student is in 8th grade and I am not sure how odd it is to be getting answers that are not whole numbers.

Now, 12 and 13 seem to be a bit trickier.

Comment: Your solution is correct. Perhaps a "numerical" answer to a few decimal places (calculator) is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.

I actually don't know what an 8th grade is, what age is that?

I think we probably came across surds sometime about being 12 years old when I was in secondary school, but it is quite a while ago, so I wouldn't be sure.

Note that they are not worked out in the exact same way. In particular, number 13 has a (slightly) different method (but the overall approach is to use Pythagoran Theorem alright).

Comment: My sister is 13, so about the same age as when you were in secondary school. I recently graduated in mathematics but studied pure math, so I am glad for the refresher here! I hadn't looked at 12 and 13 until now, trickier.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT :**

$BE=R$, $BF=R-FD$, and $BE^2=BF^2+EF^2$, where $R$ is radius of the circle.

$$\\$$

---

$$\Large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have got your answer for the questions 12 and 13 by now but here is what I think:
1. Draw an imaginary line ED 
2. TAN ∠FDE= EF/FD. Now you have the measurement for ∠FDE
3. ∠FDE is sharing the same arc with ∠ABE, Therefore ∠ABE is twice the size of ∠FDE. Now you have the measurement of ∠FDE
4. Deduct the result in step 3 from 180 to get the measurement for ∠EBF
5. Now that you have all the angle measurements in the triangle BFE and the length of EF, you should be able to use some trigonometry to find the size of BF